# Puppet showing cert in list, but cannot 'find' it

Tags: puppet

I am setting up Puppet on a few test servers: `bruno` is the puppet master and `oppenheimer` is the agent. When I start the server on `bruno` I get this output:

```
bruno$ sudo puppet cert list
"oppenheimer.home" (SHA256) D4:**:**:**:0B:2A

bruno$ sudo puppet master --verbose --no-daemonize
Notice: Starting Puppet master version 3.4.3
```

I then go to start the agent on `oppenheimer`:

```
oppenheimer$ sudo puppet agent --test --server=bruno
Exiting; no certificate found and waitforcert is disabled
```

And when I look over at `bruno` again:

```
Info: access[^/catalog/([^/]+)$]: allowing 'method' find
Info: access[^/catalog/([^/]+)$]: allowing $1 access
Info: access[^/node/([^/]+)$]: allowing 'method' find
Info: access[^/node/([^/]+)$]: allowing $1 access
Info: access[/certificate_revocation_list/ca]: allowing 'method' find
Info: access[/certificate_revocation_list/ca]: allowing * access
Info: access[^/report/([^/]+)$]: allowing 'method' save
Info: access[^/report/([^/]+)$]: allowing $1 access
Info: access[/file]: allowing * access
Info: access[/certificate/ca]: adding authentication any
Info: access[/certificate/ca]: allowing 'method' find
Info: access[/certificate/ca]: allowing * access
Info: access[/certificate/]: adding authentication any
Info: access[/certificate/]: allowing 'method' find
Info: access[/certificate/]: allowing * access
Info: access[/certificate_request]: adding authentication any
Info: access[/certificate_request]: allowing 'method' find
Info: access[/certificate_request]: allowing 'method' save
Info: access[/certificate_request]: allowing * access
Info: access[/]: adding authentication any
Info: Inserting default '/status' (auth true) ACL
Info: Not Found: Could not find certificate oppenheimer.home
Info: Not Found: Could not find certificate oppenheimer.home
Info: Not Found: Could not find certificate oppenheimer.home
Info: Not Found: Could not find certificate oppenheimer.home
Info: Not Found: Could not find certificate oppenheimer.home
```

**Notice that the server `bruno` does show the agent `oppenheimer`'s cert before I start the server. So why can it not find the cert?**

This is my config on the server:

```
bruno$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       bruno
10.0.0.7        bruno
10.0.0.10       oppenheimer

bruno$ cat /etc/puppet/puppet.conf 
[main]
logdir=/var/log/puppet
vardir=/var/lib/puppet
ssldir=/var/lib/puppet/ssl
rundir=/var/run/puppet
factpath=$vardir/lib/facter
templatedir=$confdir/templates
prerun_command=/etc/puppet/etckeeper-commit-pre
postrun_command=/etc/puppet/etckeeper-commit-post

certificate_revocation=false
server=bruno

[master]
# These are needed when the puppetmaster is run by passenger
# and can safely be removed if webrick is used.
ssl_client_header = SSL_CLIENT_S_DN 
ssl_client_verify_header = SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY
```

And here is the config on the agent:

```
oppenheimer$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       oppenheimer
10.0.0.7        bruno
10.0.0.10       oppenheimer

oppenheimer$ cat /etc/puppet/puppet.conf 
[main]
logdir=/var/log/puppet
vardir=/var/lib/puppet
ssldir=/var/lib/puppet/ssl
rundir=/var/run/puppet
factpath=$vardir/lib/facter
templatedir=$confdir/templates
prerun_command=/etc/puppet/etckeeper-commit-pre
postrun_command=/etc/puppet/etckeeper-commit-post

certificate_revocation=false
server=bruno

[master]
# These are needed when the puppetmaster is run by passenger
# and can safely be removed if webrick is used.
ssl_client_header = SSL_CLIENT_S_DN 
ssl_client_verify_header = SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY

[agent]
server=bruno
```

Both the machines are running Ubuntu Linux 14.04 with the latest updates.

Answer (score 2):

You have to sign the certificate. If the certificate was signed already then it would not show up in the output of `puppet cert list`.

```
 # puppet cert sign oppenheimer.home
```

Then `puppet agent` should run successfully.

Hope this helps.

Comment: And after signed it should show up in `puppet cert list --all`